# Looking for the equivalent of "Suck it, loser" in French

Tags: anglais, argot

I know there isn't a translation for it, since it's English slang, but is there an equivalent?

Comment: You'll have to explain in what context you are using these words. And tell us what you have found in [English French dictionaries](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/suck%20it) and why it does not suit you. And bear in mind that FL is not a translation service and not all the members understand English so you'd better explain what it means in English slang.

Comment: I agree this question could use more effort, but to help on this last point: the expression, quite different from "Suck it up" (="Don't complain"), is essentially an insulting/vulgar way to say, "You've lost and I've won. Acknowledge your inferiority!" (The "it" would be, to try to match the tone, *la bite de celui qui parle*...)

Comment: "Dans tes dents"

Answer (score 7):

"Suck it" with a vengeful connotation could be translated by "Dans les dents", "Dans ta face" (both mild), "Dans le fion" or "Dans le cul" (both very vulgar).

"loser" could be "minable", "minus", "nullos", "bon à rien", "gros blaireau" and many other variants depending on context and the age of the person saying it.

Without knowing the context, I can suggest "Dans ta face, minus !" ou "Dans le cul, gros blaireau !"

Comment: "Dans ta gueule, connard" ? (Hi Sylvain, nice to meet you, I usually don't start my conversations like this!)

Comment: @Kerkyra Hi there :) "Dans ta gueule, connard !" is as French as can be, but "connard" conveys a more general "I hate you" feeling, and other terms are better suited to convey a feeling of superiority like "loser".

Answer (score -2):

Correct translation would be : `Dans tes dents, John Doe`

Comment: "Dans tes dents" ce serait plutôt "In your face".

Comment: That seems pretty close to me — do you mean that it's too polite to be matched with "Suck it"?

Comment: @Laure vous avez raison, ma proposition est probablement trop polie par rapport aux besoins de L'OP